# Component is loading before canActivate returns the result in angular 4 when integrated with keycloak

Tags: angular, keycloak, auth-guard

I have integrated keycloak with application, I have written AuthGuard to protect specific routes.canActivate works fine but the component for the route also loading and another API calls also getting triggered in background. How to load component until canActivate returns the result.

```
AuthGuard:
-----------
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!this.keycloakService.getIsClientSecretKeyFetch()) {
      this.errorHandler._enlivenErrorhandler.handleError({"status":"401","message" :"Unable to get client details. Please contact your administrator ","url":window.location.href});
      this.router.navigate(['404'], { queryParams: { tenantId: this.cookieService.get('tenantId') } });
    }
    this.isAccessAllowed(route,state);
    return super.canActivate(route, state);
  }

  isAccessAllowed(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.authenticated) {
        this.keycloakAngular.login();
        return;
      }
      const path = route.data.path;
      this.keycloakService.isAuthorized(path).then(
        (res) => {
          let access = res;
          if (access) {
            resolve(true);
          } else {
            resolve(false);
          }
        });
      resolve(true);
    });
  }

routes.ts
-----------
RouterModule.forChild([

            {
                path: 'data-source-mongo-list',
                canActivate: [AppAuthGuard],
                data: {
                    path:'data-source-mongo-list'
                },
                component: DataSourceListComponent
            }])
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see it looks like you implemented all that OpenId stuff by yourself. From my personal experience I can't recommend this. Did you try to use angular-oauth2-oidc?
I think it is well described here: https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/07/03/authentication-in-angular-2-with-oauth2-oidc-and-guards-for-the-newest-new-router-english-version.aspx